# How to access developer tools in iBooks on macOS Monterey (version 12)

Tags: epub, apple-books

How do I access developer tools in iBooks on macOS12 (Monterey)?

We have epubs with multiple-choice questions, and we use Javascript to make them interactive (i.e. click on an option, see if you're correct). Since macOS 12 Monterey, these are no longer clickable in iBooks. All other Javascript in the epub still works fine.

We need to debug this in dev tools, but we can't seem to access dev tools in iBooks on Monterey in [the way that we did before](http://epubsecrets.com/how-to-access-the-web-inspector-for-desktop-ibooks.php) in previous macOS versions, which is [officially documented here](https://help.apple.com/itc/booksassetguide/#/itc5905301b7):

> To enable the inspector from the Terminal, execute:
>
> `defaults write com.apple.iBooksX WebKitDeveloperExtras -bool YES`
>
> In the EPUB, select any text and right-click (Control-click on Mac) and choose Show Inspector from the shortcut menu.

Comment: Wish I could help, but your question helped me (haven't upgraded to Monterey, but didn't know this was available). Thanks, hopefully you figured it out for yours.

Comment: @john-o Glad it helped! Sadly we've still not found a way to access dev tools for iBooks. It does make epub development extra tricky.